# Countdown inside laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, timer, laravel-blade, countdown

[image]

Hi guys, I'm trying to look for a way on how to make the `Time Left` column count down. I was guessing on doing it via `ajax` and updating it every minute but I guess it will affect the performance. What is the best way  to achieve this? I need it to show the real-time time left of the column also updating the values in the database. Thank you!

Comment: Which values in the database do you need to update? The countdown could be in JS and the data in the DB should be the due date, which does not need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You do not to update the time left everytime in the database, I don't think you need to even store it. You need to store the deadline (The End Date) and then the count down will be only on the client side using JavaScript as follows:

```js
let timer = function (date) {
    let timer = Math.round(new Date(date).getTime()/1000) - Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
  let minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
            if (--timer < 0) {
    timer = 0;
   }
   days = parseInt(timer / 60 / 60 / 24, 10);
   hours = parseInt((timer / 60 / 60) % 24, 10);
   minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10);
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

   days = days < 10 ? "0" + days : days;
   hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
   seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

   document.getElementById('cd-days').innerHTML = days;
   document.getElementById('cd-hours').innerHTML = hours;
   document.getElementById('cd-minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
   document.getElementById('cd-seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
  }, 1000);
 }
 
//using the function
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
timer(tomorrow);
```

```html
<span id="cd-days">00</span> Days 
<span id="cd-hours">00</span> Hours
<span id="cd-minutes">00</span> Minutes
<span id="cd-seconds">00</span> Seconds
```

Comment: Hello! So should my server return this kind of format for END DATE??? `2019-12-02 01:41:37`

Comment: You should wrap it as new Date() atg `new Date('2019-12-03 01:41:37')` and the date should be in the future